# Firefox Addon: Uploading Image

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-restartless

I would like to upload an image to a site from a Firefox Addon.

I know I can `createElement('canvas')`, convert Image data to base64 and XHR POST the data, but I would like to see if it is possible to let Firefox handle it.

Normally, a user will click BROWSE on the site, Firefox will then Open `File Upload` dialogue, select file, and click OPEN.

I would like to automate that from the context menu so that a **local file** opened by the browser (ie an image) can be uploaded to the destination directly.

Is that possible and how?

**Clarification:**

In file selection for upload via Firefox, these are the required data:
- target form
- local file location
- The action attached to the OPEN button in FILE UPLOAD dialogue box

In a context menu situation that I would like to create:
- target form: will be hard-coded in the script
- local file location: the file that is right-clicked (ie `gContextMenu.target.src`)
- The action: here is what I would like to do and attach 'command' to the function of the above button (the existing Firefox function)

That means, not manually creating `new XMLHttpRequest()` and POSTing the data, and instead using the existing function of Firefox.

In other words, manually feed the 'target form' & 'local file location' to the OPEN button function of FILE UPLOAD as if that was the process that was executed.

[image: File Upload Dialogue Box]

Comment: possible it's possible

Comment: There are multiple ways. Here's one way: (warning this guy's real sloppy) -  [upload image binary - using imageshack api ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22036442/upload-image-binary-using-imageshack-api)

Comment: Thank you but that guy is using JavaScript, canvs, XHR, which as I mentioned, was not what I was after ;)

Comment: I think you're going to have to use XHR. The difference is that you want to use FormData. You send FormData as the first agument of XHR `.send()` or `.open()` no need to base64, just use `mozGetAsFile` from canvas.

Comment: Great question man. The solution posted below learned me a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Using a DOM File

The DOM [`File` constructor actually accepts plain paths (from privileged code)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Extensions/Using_the_DOM_File_API_in_chrome_code)

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "http://example.org/");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type",
                     "application/octet-stream");
xhr.send(new File("/tmp/test.upload"));
```

This can be combined with form data.

#### Using an input stream

You can send `nsIInputStream`. So it is just a matter of knowing the path to a file, then initializing a `nsIFileInputStream`, a "super-interface" of `nsIInputStream` and `send()`ing stuff off with a proper Content-Type.

```
var {classes: Cc, interfaces: Ci, utils: Cu} = Components;

Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm");

var stream = Cc["@mozilla.org/network/file-input-stream;1"].
  createInstance(Ci.nsIFileInputStream);
stream.init(FileUtils.File("/tmp/test.upload"),
            -1, -1,
            Ci.nsIFileInputStream.DEFER_OPEN);
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "http://example.org/");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type",
                     "application/octet-stream");
xhr.send(stream);
```

This can be combined (IIRC) with [nsIMultiplexInputStream](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/xpcom/io/nsIMultiplexInputStream.idl) to construct more complex payloads.

Comment: Wow very interesting for the DOM `File`, this is available to JSM. But from JSM shouldn't we use `new FileUtils.File`? Will content-type always be `application/octet-stream` for images? Also you IIRC a lot, where are you recalling this from, I would like to go there.

Comment: Ah I think `octet-stream` is set always when using input stream, and with that way we can set `FileUtils.File('/tmp/test.upload')` (how come you didn't do `new FileUtils`?) to any file we want huh? If true this is so awesome man thanks you!

Comment: `var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();` is not available from JSM scope you have to first import `const XHR = Cc["@mozilla.org/xmlextras/xmlhttprequest;1"];` and then you can do `var xhr = new XHR()` right?

Comment: Great info Nils. Thank you..... I added more clarification to my original question which I hope explains my request. :)

Comment: I get an error with `xhr.send(new File("file:///C:/...root.png"));` saying `Exception: File error: Unrecognized path`

Comment: That's a file URI. You're supposed to just pass it a file path. `.send(new File("C:\\Temp\\test.txt"));`

Comment: How do you convert the URI to path? I have a code with `nsIIOService` + `newURI()` + `QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIFileURL)` + file.path` but that seems like a long way. Is there a shorter way?

Comment: This is getting off-topic quite rapidly. Post another question please.

Comment: @erosman and nmair What if i wanted to post other data along wit the image? Like `?data=1&data2=rawr`