# Firefox Add-on RESTClient - How to send data-binary file in the request?

Tags: rest, post, firefox-addon, binaryfiles

I am trying to use [RESTClient](http://restclient.net/) Firefox add on to post something equivalent to this:

```
curl -s -S -X POST -H "Content-type: application/zip" \
  --data-binary @./cluster-config.zip \
  http://${JOINING_HOST}:8001/admin/v1/cluster-config
```

The idea is using this Firefox add-on (RESTClient) to debug my stuff until it works. But I am stuck because I don't find the way to add a file to the request (equivalent to --data-binary parameter of curl)

**How can I include a file in the request in RestClient Firefox add-on?**

Comment: One option is `nsIFormData`: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25040513/1828637 I'm pretty sure doing  implementation of it via XPCOM in a fully featured `xhr` function I use regularly and just used a couple days ago is here: https://github.com/Noitidart/NativeShot/blob/b6e0eec22790c719dab1a781bf2e5f14ddf87887/bootstrap.js#L1403-L1407 its commented out though as I opted for `DataURL`/`base64`

Comment: Postman provides a way to that as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39037049/how-to-upload-a-file-and-json-data-in-postman, unfortunately, I didn't find such an option in the GUI of the Firefox RESTClient extension.