# How to upload a file and JSON data in Postman?

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, postman

I am using Spring MVC and this is my method:

```
/**
* Upload single file using Spring Controller.
*/
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<GenericResponseVO<? extends IServiceVO>> uploadFileHandler(
            @RequestParam("name") String name,
            @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) {

    if (!file.isEmpty()) {
        try {
            byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();

            // Creating the directory to store file
            String rootPath = System.getProperty("catalina.home");
            File dir = new File(rootPath + File.separator + "tmpFiles");
            if (!dir.exists()) {
                dir.mkdirs();
            }

            // Create the file on server
            File serverFile = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + name);
            BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(serverFile));
            stream.write(bytes);
            stream.close();

            System.out.println("Server File Location=" + serverFile.getAbsolutePath());

            return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I need to pass the session id in postman and also the file. How can I do that?

Comment: AFTER ALL IS SAID AND DONE
this fixed my issue add `[]` to the name of the file upload parameter eg.
`image[]`
`file[]`
`upload[]`

Answer (score 824, accepted):

In Postman:

- Set HTTP method type to **POST**.
- Then select Body -> form-data -> Enter your parameter name (**file**
  according to your code)
- On the right side of the Key field, while hovering your mouse over
  it, there is a **dropdown menu** to select between **Text/File**.
  Select File, then a "Select Files" button will appear in the Value
  field.

For rest of **"text" based parameters**, you can post it like normally you do with Postman. Just enter parameter name and select "text" from that right side dropdown menu and enter any value for it, hit send button. Your controller method should get called.

Comment: Why `POST`? What about `PUT`?

Comment: What do you mean by "Doesnt work"?
Why dont you show your code for us to debug issue easily?

Comment: I get the text part as `String` always. Why does it not map to my DTO?  `@PostMapping ( value = "/byImageFile", consumes = { "multipart/form-data" })
    public ResponseEntity<?> postMap( @RequestPart ( "imageFile") MultipartFile imageFile,
        @RequestPart ( "fieldsToExtract") RequestDto requestDto )`    Iam not able to send the requesst from postman at all in this case

Comment: @ArunGowda Try posting your query as new Question. As it is different from the question poster here and answer given is relevant to question posted here by OP.

Comment: I found my solution.  It won't map to `RequestDto`automatically. I took it as a string, parsed the `Json` and mapped it to `RequestDto` explicitly.

Comment: I want to send the file along with the json data not with the form-data, is there any way possible to do it ?

Comment: @SumitBadaya can i send file using raw option with other paramters in json form?

Comment: @Green Checkout Kubilay's answer regarding `PUT`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50675894/7376590

Comment: This is partly correct. You must also set the content type for each json field to application/json. You can do this by clicking the ellipsis next to the 'Bulk edit' link inside Postman.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to implement get() with postman to receive file response

Answer (score 378):

**The Missing Visual Guide**

You must *first* find the nearly-invisible pale-grey-on-white dropdown for `File` which is the magic key that unlocks the `Choose Files` button.

*After* you choose `POST`, *then* choose `Body->form-data`, *then* find the File dropdown, and *then* choose 'File', *only then* will the 'Choose Files' button magically appear:

[image: Postman POST file setup - (Text,File) dropdown highlighted]

Comment: you are correct in that the UI for this is invisible to the non-initiated.  Thank you for the visual version!

Comment: what if I have an XML body payload and the attachment?

Comment: gce's answer seems to say you can do it easily enought? I'm not sure . You might have to learn how to combine the attachment and the XML into a single document by learning about the multi-part mime format. Which isn't too complicated, you can create a multipart mime body by hand.

Comment: Two years later, the UI has not been improved any.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to implement get() with postman to receive file response?

Comment: Ah. Perhaps another picture is need. Depending on how your postman window is laid out, the response should simply appear underneath where you send the request. It displays html and images but for other files there is a save button?

Comment: Brother. You are the boss

Comment: Late 2021 update about the UI and the nearly invisible drowdown: you can only see that dropdown if **none** of the text inputs of **that line** currently holds the cursor. So move away with tab key to make it appear...

Comment: I would have never found that nearly invisible dropdown. What an odd design choice. Thank you for the heads up!

Comment: And @tuxErrante I came here looking for that answer. I believe you do the above instructions to send a file and then select the 'raw' radio button to the right. You'll then get a dropdown for format to choose - 'XML' and throw your XML in there. Not sure if that will work though - I'm going to test soon.

Comment: it's almost 2024 and still the UI has not been improved for the dropdown select

Answer (score 91):

Maybe you could do it this way:

[image: postman_file_upload_with_json]

Comment: What 6 headers have you set there?

Comment: This solution works for me. Didn't pass any headers and it's working fine. Thanks. Passing JSON was the tricky part for me. :)

Comment: Ha, clever - changed my endpoint to do that :) A bit ugly but super convenient

Comment: Can you explain what you are talking about? @ChrisKoston

Comment: @GauravSharma how did you set up JSON with form-data. Can you please share input request?

Answer (score 41):

[image]

I got confused after seeing all of the answers, I couldn't find any proper screenshot to bring the `Content Type` column. After some time, I found it by my own. Hope this will help somebody like me.

Here is the steps:

1. click on **red** marked area of postman.
2. Now check the **green** marked option (`Content Type`).
3. Now change the search content type, in the **yellow** marked area.

In my case:

1. `invoice_id_ls` (key) contains the `json` data.
2. `documents` contains the `file` data.
3. `placed_amount` contains `normal text` string.

Comment: How does the filename relate to the file to be included in the JSON attached?

Comment: Yes, this is the missing part of this quest. Spring doesn't want to treat json text as json until its content-type is set manually.

Comment: This solution worked for me, the clearest answer in this post. Normally my request body has several fields, so had to set several key-value paris as `application/json` in the `CONTENT_TYPE` column. Leaving the file as `auto` in that same column.

Comment: This is the correct answer for sending files + a json text filed in the form-data post request. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: This feature is so obtusely hidden away. Many thanks.

Answer (score 36):

Like this :

[image]

Body -> form-data -> select file

You must write "file" instead of "name"

Also you can send JSON data from Body -> raw field. (Just paste JSON string)

[image]

Comment: actually i need to pass some values and file in postman for one service is that possible

Comment: Headers? what headers to set?

Comment: The question asks for uploading json data as well, which is not covered here in this answer.

Comment: The correct way to do this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329426/spring-mvc-multipart-request-with-json

Comment: files + (json)?

Comment: @JehadNasser yup

Comment: this option saved me from creating files then reading them one by one to send to the server. here you upload the json string directly

Comment: This does not answer the question that asked

Comment: You can't utilize form-data and raw(JSON) body types at the same time (that is in the same request), it's one or another per request. OP wants to know if there is a way to send both a file with form-data and a JSON at the same time

Answer (score 20):

[image: Postman multipart form-data content-type]

Select [Content Type] from [SHOW COLUMNS] then set content-type of "application/json" to the parameter of json text.

Answer (score 19):

1. Don't give any headers.
2. Put your json data inside a .json file.
3. Select your both files one is your .txt file and other is .json file
   for your request param keys.

Comment: This is a good answer.. This can also be used for use cases where multiple file has to be uploaded along with a json payload in a multi-part payload..

Comment: This is the most correct answer if you want to send a File as well as JSON data.
Examples showing selecting a file and then the JSON data being passed as a single JSON string value or splitting the values up do not work (possibly depending on the end point but I can't verify this).
It is also mentioned here: https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/3331

Answer (score 18):

If somebody wants to send json data in form-data format just need to declare the variables like this

Postman:

[image]

As you see, the description parameter will be in basic json format, result of that:

```
{ description: { spanish: 'hola', english: 'hello' } }
```

Comment: This sadly does not work for me on Ubuntu. Anyone else facing this problem?

Answer (score 15):

Kindly follow steps from top to bottom as shown in below image.

[image: postman image]

At third step you will find dropdown of type selection as shown in below image

[image: postman dropdown]

Comment: could u please help explain or point me to a resource on how to work  with these API keys for authenticating apis ? I am using laravel admin for some project and its base code is rather confusing on how to use libraries like passport to generate API tokens. many thanks

Comment: you can pass through the Authorization tab of postman. In that Select Type: API Key and after that pass value in the key & value textbox. Once you are done with after this if you pass a parameter through the body it will automatically get authenticated.

Answer (score 15):

Body > binary > Select File

[image]

Answer (score 13):

[image]

If you need like
Upload file in **multipart** using form data and send **json** data(Dto object) in same **POST** Request

Get yor JSON object as String in Controller and make it Deserialize by adding this line

```
ContactDto contactDto  = new ObjectMapper().readValue(yourJSONString, ContactDto.class);
```

Comment: Can you tell me what are the two headers used?

Comment: Content-Type : application/json    Authorization : bearer (yourTokenString)

Comment: Yes it worked. Thanks.

I used below code and worked :

@PostMapping(value = Constant.API_INITIAL + "/uploadFile")
    public UploadFileResponse uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,String jsonFileVo) {
  FileUploadVo fileUploadVo = null;
  try {
   fileUploadVo = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonFileVo, FileUploadVo.class);
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

Comment: you can set the Content-Type for contactDtoString to application/json, you can do this for every key

Answer (score 9):

If somebody needed:

**body -> form-data**

Add field name as array

[image]

Answer (score 9):

You can send both Image and optional/mandatory parameters.

In postman, there is `Params` tab.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Use the below code in your Spring REST controller:

```
@PostMapping(value = Constant.API_INITIAL + "/uploadFile")
public UploadFileResponse uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, String jsonFileVo) {
    FileUploadVo fileUploadVo = null;
    try {
        fileUploadVo = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonFileVo, FileUploadVo.class);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

If you want to make a `PUT` request, just do everything as a `POST` request but add `_method` => `PUT` to your `form-data` parameters.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I got confused as to why it worked on `POST` but not `PUT.` earlier. Thank you!!

Comment: @kubilay this didn't work

Answer (score 5):

The way to send mulitpart data which containts a file with the json data is the following, we need to set the content-type of the respective json key fields to 'application/json' in the postman body tab like the following:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

I needed to pass both: a file and an integer. I did it this way:

1. needed to pass a file to upload:
   did it as per Sumit's answer.

   Request type : **POST**

   **Body** -> **form-data**

   under the heading **KEY**, entered the name of the variable ('file' in my backend code).

   in the backend:

   `file = request.files['file']`

   Next to 'file', there's a drop-down box which allows you to choose between 'File' or 'Text'. Chose 'File' and under the heading **VALUE**, 'Select files' appeared. Clicked on this which opened a window to select the file.

2.
needed to pass an integer:

went to:

**Params**

entered variable name (e.g.: id) under **KEY** and its value (e.g.: 1) under **VALUE**

in the backend:

```
id = request.args.get('id')
```

Worked!

Comment: It was the `file = request.files['file']`for me. Thanks, saved my day

Answer (score 2):

For each form data key you can set Content-Type, there is a postman button on the right to add the Content-Type column, and you don't have to parse a json from a string inside your Controller.

Answer (score 2):

first, set post in method and fill link API

Then select Body -> form-data -> Enter your parameter name (file according to your code)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

If you want the Id and File in one object you can add your request object to a method as standard and then within Postman set the Body to form-data and prefix your keys with your request object name. e.g. request.SessionId and request.File.

Answer (score 0):

The steps of uploading a file through postman along with passing some input data is very well discussed in below blog along with the screenshot. In this blog, the api code is written in node js. You can go through it once to have more clarity.

https://jksnu.blogspot.com/2021/09/how-to-create-post-request-with.html

Answer (score -1):

If you are using cookies to keep session, you can use **interceptor** to share cookies from browser to postman.

Also to upload a file you can use form-data tab under body tab on postman, In which you can provide data in key-value format and for each key you can select the type of value text/file. when you select file type option appeared to upload the file.

Comment: For what you are getting 500. can you please share some more details

Answer (score -2):

At Back-end part

Rest service in Controller will have mixed @RequestPart and MultipartFile to serve such Multipart + JSON request.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/executesampleservice", method = RequestMethod.POST,
consumes = {"multipart/form-data"})

@ResponseBody
public boolean yourEndpointMethod(
    @RequestPart("properties") @Valid ConnectionProperties properties,
    @RequestPart("file") @Valid @NotNull @NotBlank MultipartFile file) {
return projectService.executeSampleService(properties, file);
}
```

At front-end :

```
formData = new FormData();

formData.append("file", document.forms[formName].file.files[0]);
formData.append('properties', new Blob([JSON.stringify({
            "name": "root",
            "password": "root"                    
        })], {
            type: "application/json"
        }));
```

See in the image (POSTMAN request):

[Click to view Postman request in form data for both file and json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mosdz.png)

Answer (score -2):

To send image along with json data in postman you just have to follow the below steps .

- Make your method to post in postman
- go to the body section and click on form-data
- provide your field name select **file** from the dropdown list as shown below
- you can also provide your other fields .
- now just write your image storing code in your controller as shown below .

**postman :**
[image]

**my controller :**

```
public function sendImage(Request $request)
{
    $image=new ImgUpload;  
    if($request->hasfile('image'))  
    {  
        $file=$request->file('image');  
        $extension=$file->getClientOriginalExtension();  
        $filename=time().'.'.$extension;  
        $file->move('public/upload/userimg/',$filename);  
        $image->image=$filename;  
    }  
    else  
    {  
        return $request;  
        $image->image='';  
    }  
    $image->save();
    return response()->json(['response'=>['code'=>'200','message'=>'image uploaded successfull']]);
}
```

That's it hope it will help you