# Difficulties sending multipart/form-data request via Postman

Tags: java, rest, postman

please, this is y concern: I'll like to know how to query a web service defined as in the below code using postman for test purposes.
PS: I can't change the method signature

I have a web service like this :

```
@POST
@Path("/uploadOpenAccountRequestFiles/{requestId}")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA})
public Response uploadOpenAccountRequestFiles(@PathParam("requestId") String requestId,
        MultipartFormDataInput multipartFormDataInput)
        throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException {

    initContext();
    logger.info("DIGIBANK : uploadOpenAccountRequestFiles END: ");

    String msge = "";
    try {
        digiBean.saveToserver(requestId, multipartFormDataInput);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        msge = e.getMessage();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    org.af.webservice.Response resp = new org.af.webservice.Response(
            request.getSession().getId(), "uploadOpenAccountRequestFiles", "",
            msge.equalsIgnoreCase("OK") ? true : false, msge.equalsIgnoreCase("OK") ? false : true, "",
            msge.equalsIgnoreCase("OK") ? true : false, "Boolean", msge);

    logger.info("DIGIBANK : uploadOpenAccountRequestFiles END: ");
    return Response.ok().entity(mapper.writeValueAsString(resp)).build();
}
```

this is are images of my configurations:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U19Lu.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFX5B.png)

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39037049/how-to-upload-a-file-and-json-data-in-postman/48054400#48054400

Comment: Hello, thanks for your time, I tried to send the request like this: **http://192.168.202.210:8080/afb-fintech-api/rest/agentbanking/uploadOpenAccountRequestFiles/1**;  then follow  the example on the link your mentioned above, I received this error : HTTP 415 - Unsupported Media Type.

Comment: please, I have no content type selected in headers.and in the body, just **form-data** and the file are selected

Answer (score 0):

For calling that service, you need to pass requestId like below:

http://localhost:8080/uploadOpenAccountRequestFiles/**requestId-value-here**

For sending MultiPart data such as a file, you need to select form-data option in the body section in Postman and select the file by selecting the File dropdown. Also, make sure to set the appropriate headers for the request.

Check the below stackoverflow answer for more details:

[Tool for sending multipart/form-data request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015548/tool-for-sending-multipart-form-data-request)

Answer (score 0):

The steps of uploading a file through postman along with passing some input data along with the multipart request is very well discussed in below blog along with the screenshot. In this blog, the api code is written in node js. You can go through it once. It may give some information.

https://jksnu.blogspot.com/2021/09/how-to-create-post-request-with.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31237030)