# Sending a POST json object with image through Postman

Tags: rest, postman

I am currently sending something like this through raw category of Postman. This works fine however I cant attach an image

```
{
"user" :    {   
             "first_name": "employeeA",   
             "last_name": "smith",
             "username": "employeeA",
             "employer_image" :  --->Insert image here
             },     
"employee_zip" : 12345
}
```

However I dont know how to attach the image file. I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39037049/how-to-upload-a-file-and-json-data-in-postman) that I could instead use the form data category and send the image.So I did something like this
[image]

This does not work is there any way for me to select a file and then use raw json to point to that file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using a Base64 encoded string ?
The final JSON object would look something like this...

```
{
    "user" : {   
        "first_name" : "employeeA",   
        "last_name"  : "smith",
        "username"   : "employeeA",
        "employer_image" : "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABAQMAAAAl21bKAAAAA1BMVEUAAACnej3aAAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAAApJREFUCNdjYAAAAAIAAeIhvDMAAAAASUVORK5CYII="
    },
   "employee_zip"   : 12345       
}
```

You can find Base64 encoder details in [Mozilla Developer Website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding), and many implementations in [Github](https://github.com/dankogai/js-base64/blob/master/base64.js)

For testing purposes you can try first an [online converter](https://www.base64-image.de/), as @MistyD suggests in the comments.

Comment: looks like this is something that might work for me. Let me see if I can find something that encodes an image into base64

Comment: I am going to try this now