# How to send a request with content-type:multipart/related using a rest api client tool (postman or jemeter)

Tags: rest, testing, postman, multipart

I want to POST a request to a REST API with content-type:multipart/related containing a json part and file part like the following example:

```
--.cpjJMFx9g/PaFGcDu5w40iR)P NnR45'lhRUQ-
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
 {
      "file_id": "cid:afd1602c7720e76df92618faecc4295c@AXI.fr",
      "date": "2020-02-19T09:27:41.018Z"
    }
--.cpjJMFx9g/PaFGcDu5w40iR)P NnR45'lhRUQ-
Content-Type: image/png
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <afd1602c7720e76df92618faecc4295c@AXI.fr>
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=capture.png

<content-file>

--.cpjJMFx9g/PaFGcDu5w40iR)P NnR45'lhRUQ---
```

Did you have any solution to do the test  with postman, jemeter or any test tool?

Comment: I believe this might be answered in another post. Have a look. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39037049/how-to-upload-a-file-and-json-data-in-postman

Comment: This link concerns the type "multipart/form-data", but i need to do it with multipart/related