# How to send list of values from postman query params c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, postman, rest

Hi i need to post multiple values to the database at a single request .
[image]

Here i need to pass multiple storage address and read those values as json in c# . I had tried following code

```
var request = HttpContext.Current.Request;

string[] StorageAddress = request.Params["StorageAddress"];
```

but i am not getting response as i required how to pass multiple values through postman url params and read it in code.

****UPDATE****

[image]

Comment: What framework are you using to handle this request? e.g. API controller.
You might want to look at setting up the action on the controller to take the query parameters into part of the route as an input to the action.

Comment: If your are Web API, decorate your method parameter like this [FromQuery] string[] StorageAddress, this will do the trick.

Comment: @Joe_DM using C#

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Article/Reference: [Arrays in query params](https://medium.com/raml-api/arrays-in-query-params-33189628fa68)

Retrieve Option 1

```
var request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
string[] StorageAddress = request.Params["StorageAddress"].Split(',');
```

Retrieve Option 2

```
public IHttpActionResult Get([FromUri] string[] StorageAddress )
{
    ....
}
```

UPDATE with PostMan passing JSON 
[image]

You can use Retrieve Option 3

```
public IHttpActionResult Get(string[] StorageAddress )
{
    ....
}
```

Retrieve Option 4 with [Newtonsoft](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/)

```
var json = await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var storageAddress = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[]>(json);
```

Retrieve Option 5 for mix of json data and files. For postman passing you refer to this [How to upload a file and JSON data in Postman?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50531746/8795884).

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post()
{
    var atorageAddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["StorageAddress"].Split(',');
    var files = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files;
    List<HttpPostedFile> fileList = new List<HttpPostedFile>();
    foreach (var key in files.AllKeys)
    {
        // Do your logic here for manipulation of the files
        fileList.Add(files[key]);
    }

    return Json("OK");
}
```

**UPDATE: Retrieve JSON**

1. Set your JSON like this.

   `[{"Address":"Test Store 1"},{"Address":"Test Store 2"}]`
2. Retrieve it like this.

   `var storageAddress = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, string>>>(HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["StorageAddress"]);`

Comment: but i need to read it as json format and i cannot user second option because i need to pass image also using second option i cant pass image

Comment: @ tontonsevilla yes i know this method but i can't pass it from raw data because i also need to pass images from  formdata in that both will not work when i send request

Comment: @chethu, how about option 5.

Comment: i am passing value as `{"Address":"Test Store 1"},{"Address":"Test Store 2"}` in postman how to read Address value of each in c#

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221033/discussion-between-tontonsevilla-and-chethu).

Answer (score -1):

You can add a parameters in your controller which handled a csv param like a
StorageAddresses (ex http://localhost:30601/api/licence/seeds/application/finalsubmit?StorageAddresses=test%20score%201,test%20score%202)

You can follow this tutorial to implement it in your site https://www.strathweb.com/2017/07/customizing-query-string-parameter-binding-in-asp-net-core-mvc/

Comment: Consider rephrasing your Answer to make it sound less like a question. Please also show how the code in the link answer the Question. At present you're forcing a click-through and your Answer isn't self-contained. See ["Provide context for links"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).