# How to pass List<int> in query parameter using postman?

Tags: rest, .net-core, postman

I want to test my rest API which is accepting list in query params through postman.
Can anyone help me out in letting me know how to do that using postman?

I came across multiple question like this on stack overflow but didn't get the correct answer till now.

Comment: Did you take a look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63751641/how-to-send-list-of-values-from-postman-query-params-c-sharp

Comment: Yes, I checked - this also didn't worked for me