# How to update an enity with files using Patch method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, swagger, http-patch

I have an Entity that contain some images and I want to update it using HttpPatch method.

To create a new Style I use this method:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateStyleAsync([FromForm] StyleFiles styleFiles, [FromForm] StyleDTO style)
```

Now I'm trying to create a method to update this Style using the HttpPatch method. I tried this but there is no option to upload the file on Swagger:

```
[HttpPatch("{styleId}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PatchStyleAsync([FromForm] StyleFiles styleFiles, Guid styleId, [FromBody] JsonPatchDocument styleDto)
```

This is what I see on Swagger:
[Patch method on Swagger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Epo9l.png)

This is the DTO:

```
public class StyleDTO
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string PreviewImage { get; set; }
}
```

And this the StyleFiles class:

```
public class StyleFiles
{
    public IFormFile Image { get; set; }
}
```

I'm thinking to make two separate endpoints, one for updating the File and another one for updating the entity itself. But I would like to not do that.

Comment: I wouldn't expect swaggerui to render anything for uploading a file, regardless the http method. Have you considered using a more advanced rest tool such as [postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39037049/how-to-upload-a-file-and-json-data-in-postman)?

Answer (score 1):

`[FromForm]` and `[FromBody]` cannot be used as a parameter at the same time. Because their content-type is different. `[FromForm]` will serialize the values in the form, but `[FromBody]` pass the json data. Therefore, you have to make two separate endpoints.

I don't know whether there is a conflict between `StyleFiles` and `StyleDTO`. You can also create separate class to integrate them.

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public StyleDTO styleDTO { get; set; }
    public StyleFiles styleFiles { get; set; }
}
```

controller

```
    [HttpPatch("{styleId}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PatchStyleAsync([FromForm] ViewModel viewModel)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
```

[image]

Comment: That approach does not allow partial updates using JsonPatchDocument.
` { "op": "add", "path": "/a/b/c", "value": [ "foo", "bar" ] } `  
I will have to go with two different endpoints