# Sending a file to an API using Postman form-data

Tags: postman

I'm attempting to send a file to an API I've been developing through Postman, but the API has repeatedly failed to receive it. I initially thought this was a middleware issue, and attempted to use different modules to fix it. However, I have since realized that this is actually an issue in Postman itself

When I send the request and then review the request body in the Postman console, I can see that it fails to send the file at all, listing it as undefined.

[image: Screenshot showing the request body as sent]

I have seen a few people having this same issue, but was not able to find a solution that worked for me. I have already tried unchecking the Content-Type header, as well as closing and reopening the tab and Postman.

EDIT: I did not receive an answer to this, but I was able to find a workaround - coding a super basic html form that made a post request to the relevant endpoint. This did work, so I'm going to say this is likely a bug or settings issue in Postman itself, rather than something to do with my server's code.

Comment: This https://makolyte.com/how-to-upload-a-file-with-postman/ worked for me  Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you were in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39037049/how-to-upload-a-file-and-json-data-in-postman) thread already, but just in case,
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47071190) answer, and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55989374) might be what you need.

Comment: I've attempted the solutions depicted here (sending two items, one "file" item containing the file and one "json" item containing the param keys with its content type set to application/json) - they do not work.

I am still seeing the file listed as undefined in the request body - see here, https://imgur.com/a/ZsvEft8