# Translate informatica Documentation into REST API Call (Postman)

Tags: postman, rest, informatica

I am working on importing data into Informatica Reference360 and struggling to interpret documentation to construct an API call in POSTMAN.

Here is the example they are giving

```
POST https://use4-mdm.dm-us.informaticacloud.com/rdm-service/external/v1/import HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=6o2knFse3p53ty9dmcQvWAIx1zInP11uCfbm
IDS-SESSION-ID: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

--6o2knFse3p53ty9dmcQvWAIx1zInP11uCfbm
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=file; filename=import-code-values.csv


--6o2knFse3p53ty9dmcQvWAIx1zInP11uCfbm
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=importSettings
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8

{ 
  "delimiter":"COMMA",
  "textQualifier":"DOUBLE_QUOTE",
  "codepage":"UTF8",
  "dateFormat":"ISO",
  "containerType":"CODELIST",
  "containerId":"9ab3201990a54dcdc86f54cf",
  "startingRow":null
}
--6o2knFse3p53ty9dmcQvWAIx1zInP11uCfbm--
```

The parts I do not understand:

1. what is this for: `boundary=6o2knFse3p53ty9dmcQvWAIx1zInP11uCfbm`.Should I put it in header as well?
2. What is this and where should I use it (are these two alternatives and only one should be used)?

```
--6o2knFse3p53ty9dmcQvWAIx1zInP11uCfbm
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=file; filename=import-code-values.csv

--6o2knFse3p53ty9dmcQvWAIx1zInP11uCfbm
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=importSettings
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8

...

--6o2knFse3p53ty9dmcQvWAIx1zInP11uCfbm--
```

3. How should I pass the actual file for import, should it be in body (form-data)?
4. If so which parts of the API payload should be in raw and which in form-data?

The [link](https://docs.informatica.com/master-data-management-cloud/reference-360/current-version/reference-360/reference-360-rest-api/using-rest-apis-to-import-and-export/importing-code-values.html) to documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own questions:

> what is this for: boundary=6o2knFse3p53ty9dmcQvWAIx1zInP11uCfbm.Should I put it in header as well?

- this is generated automatically in the header by postman

> What is this and where should I use it (are these two alternatives and only one should be used)?

- both of them should

> If so which parts of the API payload should be in raw and which in form-data?

- everything should be input in body - form data

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Basically, your POST request requires 2 parts:

1.Upload file csv

```
--6o2knFse3p53ty9dmcQvWAIx1zInP11uCfbm
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=file; filename=import-code-values.csv
```

2.Json object

```
--6o2knFse3p53ty9dmcQvWAIx1zInP11uCfbm
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=importSettings
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
```

You can check the similar question here:
[How to upload a file and JSON data in Postman?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39037049/how-to-upload-a-file-and-json-data-in-postman)