# How to translate curl -T command to postman?

Tags: http, curl, postman

I have this curl command that works perfectly:

`curl -v -H "x-amz-server-side-encryption:aws:kms" -T ~/Downloads/myfile.csv "http://example.com"`

I'm trying to translate this command to postman and it doesn't work. I'm trying to send a PUT command, attaching a file using form-data, but I guess that's not right.

This is my postman setup that doesn't work:

[image]

Comment: Please do check https://stackoverflow.com/a/67474044/6720372

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue, I needed to send the body as "binary" type, and upload the file there.