# How to test file upload into storage in firebase emulator?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I have a UI which will receive a file from the user/the user uploads a file which is stored in firebase storage. How to test this in emulator? Which storage bucket should I give? The real storage bucket or emulator bucket?

Comment: You just upload file from postman. you can take reference from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39037889/10182897)

Comment: Why do I have to use postman? I want to see if the files are getting added in firebase storage without deploying.

Comment: to send the request to specific function

Answer (score 1):

To test your Cloud Functions code for uploading a file to a bucket in Cloud Storage using Emulator you need to use the `bucket name of Storage Emulator`. By default the emulator suite will have a bucket named `project-id.appspot.com`, which is also the name of the default bucket for production Firebase Storage.

I found this link on [Using Firebase Emulator for Testing File Upload to Firebase Storage Using Firebase Functions](https://dev.to/aaronksaunders/using-firebase-emulator-for-testing-file-upload-to-firebase-storage-using-firebase-functions-2h1), that contains a video demonstrating the whole process of using Emulator, which I think is really useful.