# test a file upload in postman

Tags: laravel, file-upload

i am creating a method that should upload a file to an api.the method isn't uploading the file into the specific folder.and upon testing on postman i get a 200 ok status code but the file isn't uploaded on sending it at postman.[image: on the postman]

this is the method in the imagecontroller

```
 public function pushimage(Request $request)
 {          
  $file=$request->file('image');
  if($request->hasFile('image')){
    $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $newimage=rand() . '.' . $extension;
    $file->move(public_path() . ("/images/product/fileimage/"), $newimage);
    return response()->json($newimage);
}else{
    return response()->json('file not found');
}
```

}

this is the api route

```
Route::post('/push_image','imagecontroller@pushimage');
```

upon uploading the file in the body section in postman it returns the response of "file not found". i havent understood what am doing it wrong to prevent the execution of the function.

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39037049/how-to-upload-a-file-and-json-data-in-postman?

Comment: yes and indeed i found the answer there on my postman i hadnt selected the content-Type

Comment: Post an answer and mark it resolved

Answer (score 0):

i had forgotten to tick this button here [image: correct answer] in postman.also add the boundary and define it

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).