# Postman with "body" (json) and files (multipart) together in 1 restful request

Tags: java, rest, postman

How do I use Postman to send queries with body (in json format) and files (in multipart) format at the same time?

I think I should use Postman->Body->Raw although I can't find an example on the Web.  Anyone can kindly teach me?  Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39037196/9192223

Comment: @hiren it's not a duplicate.  The json in your example is in form-data (with key) and not in body (without key).  

My API specification is such that the json is in body.  Can this actually be done?

Comment: You can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39037049/how-to-upload-a-file-and-json-data-in-postman) for your question.

Comment: So instead of form-data, you can select raw and add your json there.

Comment: yeah @hiren , agree.  But how to select raw and add my json+multipart files?  Can point me to a resource?

Comment: @SachinMishra , like what hiren has posted, I want the json to be in the body and not some form-data with key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In postman, set method type to **POST**.

Then select Body -> form-data -> Enter your parameter name (**file** according to your code)

On the right side of the Key field, while hovering your mouse over it, there is a **dropdown menu** to select between **Text/File**. Select File, then a "Select Files" button will appear in the Value field.

For rest of **JSON data**, you can click on raw and enter your JSON data there.

[image]

Comment: It only sends one or the other the way you have it, depending on which radio button is selected when you hit send.