# Postman - Http Post (JSON Body And File Upload)

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, rest, postman

I'm working on a springboot project and I have entity called `Event` , where I need to create a event with `POST` request. When creating the event I need to upload `company_logo` along with it. I wrote the necessary codes and tried the API with postman. But Unfortunately, I'm facing difficulty when trying to upload image with the json body.

Here is my Event Entity

```
package com.example.attendingsystem.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@Entity
public class Event {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank(message = "Event Name cannot be blank")
    private String eventName;

    private String eventType;

    @NotBlank(message = "Event location cannot be blank")
    private String location;

    @NotNull
    private LocalDateTime startTime;

    @NotNull
    private LocalDateTime endTime;

    @Lob
    private byte[] company_logo;

    @Lob
    private byte[] event_flyer;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getEventName() {
        return eventName;
    }

    public void setEventName(String eventName) {
        this.eventName = eventName;
    }

    public String getEventType() {
        return eventType;
    }

    public void setEventType(String eventType) {
        this.eventType = eventType;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getStartTime() {
        return startTime;
    }

    public void setStartTime(LocalDateTime startTime) {
        this.startTime = startTime;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getEndTime() {
        return endTime;
    }

    public void setEndTime(LocalDateTime endTime) {
        this.endTime = endTime;
    }

    public byte[] getCompany_logo() {
        return company_logo;
    }

    public void setCompany_logo(byte[] company_logo) {
        this.company_logo = company_logo;
    }

    public byte[] getEvent_flyer() {
        return event_flyer;
    }

    public void setEvent_flyer(byte[] event_flyer) {
        this.event_flyer = event_flyer;
    }
}
```

EventService class
package com.example.azendattendingsystem.service;

```
import com.example.attendingsystem.dto.EventDTO;
import com.example.attendingsystem.entity.Event;
import com.example.attendingsystem.repository.EventRepo;
import jakarta.transaction.Transactional;
import org.modelmapper.ModelMapper;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
@Transactional
public class EventService {

    @Autowired
    private EventRepo eventRepo;

    @Autowired
    private ModelMapper modelMapper;

    public EventDTO saveEvent(EventDTO eventDTO){
        eventRepo.save(modelMapper.map(eventDTO, Event.class));
        return eventDTO;
    }
}
```

And the EventController class
package com.example.azendattendingsystem.controller;

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/api/event")
@CrossOrigin
public class EventController {

    @Autowired
    private EventService eventService;

    @PostMapping("/saveEvent")
    public EventDTO saveEvent(@RequestBody EventDTO eventDTO){
        return eventService.saveEvent(eventDTO);
    }

}
```

I'm beginner to springboot and I just need to know how to send image along with the json object in postman.

Here is the sample json object that I have tried:

```
{
    "eventName":"Test Event -3",
    "eventType":"Test Event Type -3",
    "location":"Jaffna",
    "startTime":"2019-01-13T17:08:00.411",
    "endTime":"2019-01-13T17:10:00.411",
    "company_logo":null,
    "event_flyer": null
}
```

Can someone help me in this issue?

**UPDATE**

I have changed my EventService class as follows:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class EventService {

    @Autowired
    private EventRepo eventRepo;

    @Autowired
    private ModelMapper modelMapper;

    public Event saveEvent(byte[] company_logo, EventDTO eventDTO){
        Event event=new Event();
        event.setEventName(eventDTO.getEventName());
        event.setEventType(eventDTO.getEventType());
        event.setLocation(eventDTO.getLocation());
        event.setStartTime(eventDTO.getStartTime());
        event.setEndTime(eventDTO.getEndTime());
        event.setCompany_logo(company_logo);

        return eventRepo.save(event);
    }
}
```

And EventController class as follows:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/api/event")
@CrossOrigin
public class EventController {

    @Autowired
    private EventService eventService;

    @PostMapping(value = "/saveEvent", consumes = {"multipart/form-data"})
    public EventDTO saveEvent(@RequestParam(value = "company_logo", required = false) MultipartFile company_logo, @RequestBody EventDTO eventDTO) throws IOException {
        byte[] logo = null; // or set to an empty byte array if preferred
        if (company_logo != null && !company_logo.isEmpty()) {
            logo = company_logo.getBytes();
        }
        // call the saveEvent method in your EventService class and pass the eventDTO and logo parameters
        Event savedEvent = eventService.saveEvent( logo, eventDTO);
        // create a new EventDTO object and populate it with the savedEvent data
        EventDTO savedEventDTO = new EventDTO();
        savedEventDTO.setEventName(savedEvent.getEventName());
        savedEventDTO.setEventType(savedEvent.getEventType());
        savedEventDTO.setLocation(savedEvent.getLocation());
        savedEventDTO.setStartTime(savedEvent.getStartTime());
        savedEventDTO.setEndTime(savedEvent.getEndTime());
        // return the savedEventDTO object
        return savedEventDTO;
    }

}
```

And tried the postman for POST request. But I'm getting warning ,

```
WARN 21308 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content-Type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=--------------------------666943417236077820793463;charset=UTF-8' is not supported]
```

[image]

Comment: try this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39037049/how-to-upload-a-file-and-json-data-in-postman

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue but I resolved it by doing this

```
set Content-type=application/JSON in the header section of Postman
```

Comment: I tried with that. But it doesn't worked for me