# Firefox addon uploading canvas contents to imgur

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, imgur

I am writing an addon in firefox that automatically sends the contents of a canvas to imgur. I have already built a similar extension in chrome, where it works as expected, so I know that the usage of imgurs API is correct. When I use the same approach in the Firefox addon, I always get this response:

```
{
"data": {
    "error": "Image format not supported, or image is corrupt.",
    "request": "/3/upload",
    "method": "POST"
},
"success": false,
"status": 400
}
```

This is what I use to extract the image data and send it to the imgur API:

```
Request({
   url: 'https://api.imgur.com/3/upload',
   contentType : 'json',
   headers: {
       'Authorization': 'Client-ID ' + imgurClientID
   },
   content: {
   type: 'base64',
   key: imgurClientSecret,
   name: 'neon.jpg',
   title: 'test title',
   caption: 'test caption',
   image: getImageSelection('image/jpeg').split(",")[1]
},
onComplete: function (response) {
    if (callback) {
       callback(response);
    } else {
         var win = window.open(response['data']['link'], '_blank');
         win.focus();
         closeWindow();
    }
}


}).post();
```

and this is used to get a selection from a canvas and get the dataurl of that selection:

```
function getImageSelection(type) {
    //Create copy of cropped image
    var mainImageContext = mainImage.getContext('2d');
    var imageData = mainImageContext.getImageData(selection.x, selection.y, selection.w, selection.h);

    var newCanvas = tabDocument.createElement("canvas");
    newCanvas.width = selection.w;
    newCanvas.height = selection.h;

    newCanvas.getContext("2d").putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);

    return mainImage.toDataURL(type)
}
```

I have tried everything: using the dataurl from the original canvas (mainImage), getting the dataUrl without any type, this: `.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");`

But imgur keeps complaining about bad format.

Comment: I did something like this except to imageshack seen here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22036442/upload-image-binary-using-imageshack-api warning that is old code and very ugly just use as reference. if i had to do the same today i would do it differently

Comment: I also found this js demo: https://github.com/eirikb/gifie/blob/gh-pages/app.js which might help fix any api mistakes.

Comment: Are you beasing the `"Bearer :" + token`?

Comment: Hey @Consec did you figure this one out yet?

Comment: Hi @Noitidart. First of all thank you very much for your responses. I have been quite busy lately, so only now had the time to have a look at what you linked. Unfortunately I wasn't really able to get a good response when using the parameters like in the example. I did however stop focusing on the image data and had a look at the usage of the Request module of firefox, which in the end was causing the bad request. (see response). Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, it turned out that the usage of the Request module of the Firefox addon SDK was wrong.

Instead of using `contentType` to provide the type of the content (like in jquery/ajax), you have to use `dataType`. See below:

```
Request({
        url: 'https://api.imgur.com/3/upload',
        dataType : 'json',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Client-ID ' + imgurClientID
        },
        content: {
            type: 'base64',
            key: imgurClientSecret,
            name: 'neon.jpg',
            title: 'test title',
            caption: 'test caption',
            image: getImageSelection('image/jpeg', true)
        },
        onComplete: function (response) {
            response = JSON.parse(response.text);
            if (callback) {
                callback(response);
            } else {
                var win = window.open(response['data']['link'], '_blank');
                win.focus();
                closeWindow();
            }
        }
    }).post();
```

Comment: Thanks for this awesome share! I actually need to do the same exact thing like this week haha